# Only first control of dynamic created comboboxes has edited style template?

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, styles

I have a ItemsControl that creates dynamically some ComboBoxes. I have my own style, but for some reason only the first ComboBox has that style.

```
<ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Margin="10,0,10,10">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
               <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectsList}" 
                         Style="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}"
                         SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Information not enough to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @LeiYang i just edited the basic ComboBox template.